# How does google calendar knows which events to include in sync?

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-calendar-api, google-python-api

I want to sync the events in my server side application with Google calendar events. I read about https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync but I'm not sure how it selects events? Are they per developer application or per user or per user or per user per calendar? or something else? If it is per user, is there any way to get all the changes for events created withmy application or associated with users of my application?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to specify which event to sync. But as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#initial_full_sync), "you can optionally restrict the list request using request parameters if you only want to synchronize a specific subset of resources." Hope this information helps.

Comment: I am still not sure which events it is going to include? All the events of a specific user?